# SQL query to Find a user hits (or visits) more than two times in last day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the best way to find out that the count of user visits are more than two time in last day?

I'm using this for getting total count of them:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT( DISTINCT [UserID] ) 
FROM UserHit 
WHERE DateOfHit BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()))
AND CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) 
AND LEN( [UserID]) > 1
```

I guess I need one more hit than distinct value. With this query:

```
SELECT 
    UserID, 
    COUNT (UserID) 
FROM UserHit 
WHERE DateOfHit BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()))
AND CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) 
AND LEN( [UserID]) > 1
GROUP BY 
UserID HAVING COUNT([UserID]) > 2
```

I can find out how many user are hitting more than two time in last day. I made some change to last one:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(x.b)
FROM (
     SELECT 
         UserID AS b, 
         COUNT (UserID) AS a 
     FROM UserHit 
     WHERE DateOfHit BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) 
     AND CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) 
     AND LEN( [UserID]) > 1
     GROUP BY
         UserID HAVING COUNT([UserID]) > 2
     ) AS x
```

Is the last one return correct answer?

Comment: Looks fine to me, but be aware that any hit at midnight today will be counted in the query, even though you only want hits yesterday. You may want to use `DateOfHit >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) AND DateOfHit < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())`.

Comment: [Aaron Bertrand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) has written two good articles on this. [Mishandling date range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) and [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)